# Get only the IP Adress in Anaconda Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, anaconda, ip-address

I want to get the Output of my Ip Address only inside the Anaconda Powershell in Windows.

```
curl https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

Gives me the following:

```
    StatusCode        : 200
    StatusDescription : OK
    Content           : 22.031.123.456
    RawContent        : HTTP/...
                        ...
                        ...
                    ...
                    ...
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                    Date: ...
                    Via:...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[..., *], [...], [...],
                    [..., ...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : ...
RawContentLength  : ...
```

As you can see, "Content" shows my IP Adress. But I can't get the IP-Address without any other informations.

Note: "curl api.ipify.org" and "curl ipinfo.io/ip" and others are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Well, `curl` is just an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` in Powershell, so if you're expecting other output i.e. from some Windows curl install, you won't see it unless you remove the alias in PowerShell. That being said, if you just want the IP address you can do `(curl https://ipinfo.io/ip).Content`.

Comment: content in example is definitively not an IP address

Comment: Good points, @Ash, but there's no need to remove the alias - simply invoke the executable with `curl.exe`

Comment: @mklement0 fair point. That one still slips my mind, but of course things like `where.exe` still work when you specify the extension.

Comment: What does this have to do with Anaconda? Conda adds some environment variables at launch, but PowerShell is still a Microsoft Windows application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ***Windows PowerShell*, `curl`** does *not* refer to the external `curl.exe` *program*; instead, it **is a built-in alias for PowerShell's [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet**.

In order **to invoke `curl.exe`, *include the filename extension, `.exe`***:

```sh
curl.exe ipinfo.io/ip  # Note: The https:// part isn't strictly needed.
```

Note that this is **no longer necessary in *PowerShell (Core) v6+***, where the `curl` alias has been removed, along with others, so as not to shadow external programs that come with the operating system.

---

Also note that **you could also have used the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet**, which - unlike `Invoke-WebRequest`, which returns a *wrapper object* around the actual data - returns the response data *directly* (and, as applicable, parses XML data into `[xml]` instances and JSON data into `[pscustomobject]` instances); its built-in alias is `irm`:

```sh
irm ipinfo.io/ip  # irm == Invoke-RestMethod
```

---

As a general tip: **To determine which command** (a PowerShell-native one or an external program) **a given name such as `curl` refers to, use the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet**.

- By default, the *effective* command by that name will be listed.
- If you add the `-All` switch, you'll potentially see *shadowed* command forms.

  - On Windows, if an external program is shadowed, you can still invoke it by excluding the `.exe` extension, as shown.
  - Generally, if a shadowed command is of a *different type* than the effective command, you can use the `Get-Command`'s `-Type` parameter to target the shadowed command and invoke it via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); e.g., the (less desirable) alternative to appending `.exe` on Windows would be:

    ```
    & (Get-Command -Type Application curl) ipinfo.io/ip
    ```